# Powershell dies during "copy-item" when using rightclick->open with but is fine when opening the path manual in powershell

Tags: powershell, file, copy

i got a powershell script that copies alot of files from a path with some filters.

The very odd behaviour:
When I open the powershell script using:
Rightclick->run with powershell (or doubleclick)

The script DIES at copy command.

When I Open a blank powershell,
go with "cd" to the path where the script is located
and then run the Shellscript using \run.ps1

Then it works fine.

An echo of echo "$($pwd)" is IDENTICAL in both cases.

Is there a known bug or anything I can do to make it work using the rightclick method?

The relevant line of my script. When I comment out the "Copy-Item" path the script works normally.

```
if($null -eq $env:DEVROOT) {
    echo "Error: Please configure Windows environment-variable DEVROOT 
to the root-folder of your projects."
    pause
    return
}

$devRootPath = "$env:DEVROOT"

$copyExcludes = ".git",".svn",".idea",".vscode"
$destinationPath = "code-temp-store\"
Get-ChildItem "$($devRootPath)\lma\" | Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $copyExcludes} | 
Copy-Item -Destination $destinationPath -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: **1)** You're not using the `Copy-Item`, instead you write `Copy-` **whitespace** `Item`. **2)** your excludes array contains only extensions, so `$_.Name -notin $copyExcludes` won't work and will pass any file. **3)** I don't see `$devRootPath` defined anywhere in your code. **4)** it is unclear whether you want to copy just files or directories too.

Comment: @up
1) The Copy - Whitespace accidently happened while copying my code over from editor to Stackoverflow. Had linebreak that looked odd, wanted to take it "in place" and accidently made a misstake. However I fixed the Post and its identical to my code now.
2) the excludes WORK, otherwise I would have .git folders and such in my copy-temp-store which I do NOT have.
3) $devRootPath is an environment var. I forgot to paste that I updated the post.
4) I want to copy files AND directories "as is". Entire structure.